# How to get star rating review from user to mogoDB and again get it in UI by React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-router

In a react project I just want to  add a feature where Customer can rate the product out of 5 star and after his rating this data will be posted in the MongoDB database automatically.

And the second part is according to several customer's reviews this rating of that specific product will be updated automatically i.e I want to get the update from MongoDB and show it in the UI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.